# R How to make smoother looking plots of oscillations

Tags: r

When plotting oscillations in R, e.g., using the package desolve,

```
df1 <-function(t,y,mu)( list(c(y[2],mu*y[1]^3-y[1]+0.005*cos(t))))
library (deSolve)
yini<-c(y1=0,y2=0)
df2 <-ode(y=yini,func=df1, times=0:520,parms=0.1667)
plot(df2,type="l",which="y1",ylab="Displacement",xlab="Time", main="")
```

I get raggedy plots such as:

[image: raggedy plot in R]

instead of a smooth plot (not done in R) such as:

[image: smooth plot not in R]

Does anyone know of a way to obtain a smoother plot in R instead of a raggedy one when displaying oscillations?  Note that it is not just a matter of the difference in scale and I am not looking for a smoothing filter.

Thanks,

Comment: Would you please mark the answer below accepted if you are satisfied with it? That would save the time of those who read your post to give you an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I generated your plot in R and exported it as PDF.  I zoomed in on it and it's quite lovely.  I can't see the problem you're talking about there.  Therefore, there are some scaling issues or something with a raster format that are causing the issue. Perhaps you're pasting into Word and that's giving you a raster image that's bad. The plot that R is making, at a logical level, is great in spite of the one you posted.  It's even better than the comparison plot you put up.

It's possible that you're generating the plot in a raster format and not setting a high enough resolution and size.  Try tiff('filname', 1200, 1200, 300) for a good raster image of it.  I did notice that when exporting to raster formats it was easy to make your plot into a fine mess with default png or jpg settings that would just smear things.

Maybe you really wanted to sample in your function at a higher resolution, something not done in the comparison plot.  If that's the case then it's relatively easy.  Change 0:520 to seq(0, 520, 0.1).  That's an even nicer plot, as shown below (much better than shown as PDF, EPS, or SVG).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful suggestions.  I am still baffled as I too saved to pdf (no use of Word) and still get raggedy plots.  I double-checked after your reply. I tried your seq suggestion for higher resolution.  It helped but there are still jagged lines (nothing like your plot).  I am using the latest version of R and Windows 7.  Is there a different device I should select or a different way to save to pdf than "c/osc.pdf"?

Comment: Assuming you're using a pdf device.. no.  Now it's a Windows 7 question for the PDF version (I made mine on OS X).  Does it look better if you print it?  I'm hoping that if you try a high res bitmap version you might be better off.  Try using the bmp or png devices with the settings I've given above (better yet, 1500, 1500, 300).

Comment: Thank you again for your time and helpful advice.  I tried the png device settings but got the same plot as before. I will try it on a MAC to see if it an OS problem.

Comment: @Carey: As John suggested above, change the following line in your code to: df2<-ode(y=yini,func=df1,times=seq(0,520,0.1),parms=0.1667) The integrator (function ode) needs a smaller step size to get a less "digitized" result. If you use times=seq(0,520,0.01) you'll get even more steps.

Comment: @Carey: To save as a pdf file, add a pdf() statement above the plot() statement and a dev.off() statement after the plot() statement: pdf(file = "junk.pdf", width=12, height=12) plot(df2,type="l",which="y1",ylab="Displacement",xlab="Time", main="")
dev.off()